# Display values from database in input tag value in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the values from database using the id and display it in the value in `<input>` using PHP here is my code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'core/init.php';
$id = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '');
 $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = '{$id}'");
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $first_name = $res['first_name'];
  $last_name = $res['last_name'];
    $mobile_number = $res['mobile_number'];
}
 ?>
<form action="personal_details.php" method="post" id="personal_details">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="First_Name" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" class="form-control form-control-lg"
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){ echo $_POST['first_name'];}?>" style="width:770px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <label for="Last_Name" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" class="form-control form-control-lg"
  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){ echo $_POST['last_name'];}?>" style="width:770px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-7">
  <label for="mobile_number" style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Mobile Phone Number</label>
  <input type="tel" name="mobile_number" id="monu" class="form-control form-control-lg"
  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mobile_number'])){ echo $_POST['mobile_number'];}?>" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="UPDATE" name="submit_0" style="width:770px;" id="button_0">
  </div>
</div><div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

But it didn't work the fields are all empty... I've tried `<?php echo $first_name ?>` but still didn't work I got a message that says Notice: Undefined variable: first_name.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the values you want are the values from the database result, but the values you're including in your inputs are from `$_POST` instead.

If this form submits to itself rather than another page, the `$_POST` values will be there and the inputs will have whatever values were submitted, but assuming you're loading the from from somewhere else based on the id, they won't be there when the form initially loads, only after it is submitted, and even then they will be the posted values rather than the values from the database.

You should be using the `$first_name`, `$last_name`, and `$mobile_number` variables you created at the top.

e.g. instead of

```
value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){ echo $_POST['first_name'];}?>"
```

use

```
value="<?php echo $first_name ?>"
```

---

By the way, the while loop is probably not necessary since you're just fetching one record, and if you are not going to use a prepared statement to include `$id` in the query, you should at least cast it to an int (assuming the id is an int).

Comment: First, the form submits to the same page. Second, I forgot to mention that I've tried `<?php echo $first_name ?>` but still didn't work I got a message that says Notice: Undefined variable: first_name. Also, I edited my question.

Comment: Okay. If that variable is undefined, then it looks like the query didn't return anything. How is `$_POST['id']` set when the page loads? I guess it probably loads from another page with a list of links to this update form?

Comment: Load from another page ??!! And what do you mean by How is $_POST['id'] set when the page loads? I don't understand... What should I do now ??

Comment: If `$_POST['id']` isn't set when the page loads, `$id` will be set to an empty string and the query won't return a record, so `$first_name` etc. won't be set. I'm just asking where `$_POST[id']` comes from, since the select query depends on that value.

Comment: I fixed the probem :) Thanks @Don't Panic :)